# How to write custom where condition raw query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

How to write this sql query as sequelize query?

```
select * from chats where senderId + receiverId = 25
```

I want to use above query where condition in where clause of sequelize which is written below.

```
const options = {
            page: req.params.pageNo, // Default 1
            paginate: 25, // Default 25
            order: [['id', 'DESC']],
            include: [
                {
                    model: db.users,
                    required: true,
                    as: 'senderUser',
                    attributes: ['id', 'name', 'email', 'mobileNumber', 'profilePic'],
                },
                {
                    model: db.users,
                    required: true,
                    as: 'receiverUser',
                    attributes: ['id', 'name', 'email', 'mobileNumber', 'profilePic'],
                },
            ],
            where: {
                //here i need condition 
            },
        };

    db.chats
        .paginate(options)
        .then(result => {
            let apiData = { pages: result.pages, total: result.total, chats: result.docs };
            return _RL.apiResponseOk(res, 'Messages', apiData);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return _RL.serverError(res);
        });
```

Comment: What if you perform query and then paginate? would it work?

Comment: could you please write some example?

Comment: sequelize
  .query('select * from chats where senderId + receiverId = 25', { raw: true })
  .paginate(options) . something like this, its not tested I haven't env but should work. and options without where

Comment: will association work with this?

Comment: ahh I see, then we need join in raw query, so basicaly you can  get your desired data (join necessary tables, add where clause) and then paginate result. If you make some fidler or something similar I can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write aggregate query

```
await Chats.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            'total':{$add:['$senderId','$receiverId']}
        }
    },
    {
        $match:{
            'total':{$eq:25}
        }
    }
])
```

I'm assuming both senderId & receiverId are Numbers

Comment: Please check again i have added more details.